# Why does conda not install the most recent version of spyder from conda-forge

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, conda-forge

Why/how does `conda update --all` decide to upgrade to a build of a conda-forge package (spyder in this case), which does **not** seem to be the most recent one?

I do have a `.condarc` file with content

```
    channels:
     - conda-forge
     - defaults
```

Moreover when I do `conda search spyder --channel conda-forge | grep forge | grep 4.1 | grep py37` I get

```
    spyder      4.1.0  py37hc8dfbb8_0  conda-forge         
    spyder      4.1.1  py37hc8dfbb8_1  conda-forge
```

I.e. there seem to be `4.1.*` versions on this channel.

**However**, all I am getting up to with `conda update --all` is

```
    ~>conda list | grep spyder
    spyder      4.0.1  py37_0    conda-forge
```

Why is this happening? Ist this proper? What am I missing?

Just to clarify: I am not 'pinning' the version of any other package on my system.
Moreover if I look into all packages installed on my system, by no means there are only py37_0 builds installed. In fact, there are many of such cryptic 'manyascii_*' builds installed via `conda update --all`.

**UPDATE:**

This is definitely no 'answer' to the original question - just an unclear fix out of nowhere. What I did was to switch the channel for `conda` back and fro between `pkgs/main` and `conda-forge` for no particular reason (just hoping it might fix some issue in conda). After that it still did not want to `update` to spyder 4.1.1, however it did allow me to `install` 4.1.1 (i.e. with `conda install spyder=4.1.1`. This is certainly not proper behavior, but some hiccup of conda.

Comment: I would try `conda install spyder=4.1.1` and see whether the packages conda tries to remove give you a hint about incompatibilities.

Comment: I tried this, but stopped the process after ~5 hours. I'm getting: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done, Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Solving environment: / Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue I sometimes have, too, and it's not so linear the cause.

The first reason could be the [channel priority](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html), you could try to disable it completely with `channel_priority: disabled` or launching with "--

The second could be the dependency: maybe something else you need to upgrade is not there, or something would be downgraded for upgrading your *spyder* package and the best compromise found by the resolver is not what you expect.

The third could be that when you first installed *spyder* you did it by specifying the version, which *softly* pinned it.

The fourth could be resolver misses the points, it happens sometimes: you should explicitly tell what packages you absolutely want to upgrade, like `conda update spyder --all`. Also, you could explicitly tell what packages to *aggressive upgrade*, the configuration "aggressive_update_packages".

Answer (score 0):

a brute force fix.

Set a temporrary `$HOME` somewhere like `/u/user/condatemp/` and make sure there is no `.condarc` within that directory.

Navigate there - create your environment. When you install `spyder` try to use the `channel/label/labelname` method.

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/blah-blah spyder -y`

Hope this helps